# MongoDB Aggregation $sort don't order my arraylist

Tags: mongodb

I have a list of **Orders** and I need to group them and know occurrences of orders by zones, that's why a do a **$group** and create a variable *count* by a **$sum**

This is my pipeline:

```
[{
$match: {
    "status": "delivered",
    "created_at": {
        $lte: ISODate("2021-12-31T01:11:11.000Z")
    },
    "created_at": {
        $gte: ISODate("2021-01-01T01:11:11.000Z")
    },
    "type": "delivery",
}
}, {
$project: {
    "customer_id": 1,
    "coverage_area_id": "$address.coverage_id",
}
}, {
$group: {
    "_id": {
        "customer_id": "$customer_id",
        "coverage": "$coverage_area_id"
    },
    "coverage_area_id": {
        $first: "$coverage_area_id"
    },
    "count": {
        $sum: 1
    },
}
}, {
$group: {
    "_id": "$_id.customer_id",
    "items": {
        "$addToSet": {
            "coverage_id": "$coverage_area_id",
            "occurs": "$count",
        }
    },
}
}, {
$sort: {
    "items.occurs": 1
}
}]
```

And this is a result output:

```
_id:"f487a0eaa67da18"
    items:Array
        0:Object
            coverage_id: ObjectId("784c5718cf0d72")
            occurs:4
        1:Object
            coverage_id: ObjectId("317922f03c8c70")
            occurs:3
        2:Object
            coverage_id: ObjectId("317922f03c8c65")
            occurs:2
        3:Object
            coverage_id: ObjectId("15cfab3866a811")
            occurs:1
        4:Object
            coverage_id: ObjectId("1ff92c160a12d3")
            occurs:9
```

I need than the result of **occurs:9** be sorted as **the first** value but I don't see clearly why this is not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this question : [mongodb sorting children of an array in a document [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797209/mongodb-sorting-children-of-an-array-in-a-document/44797698#44797698)

I try the suggestion of [@kewne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3082668/kewne)

And change on my pipeline:

```
$addToSet -> $push
```

And before the last **$group** I do:

```
$sort{
    "_id.customer_id" : 1, "count" : -1
}
```

So first sort all the data individually, then when I do the last $group the data is correctly ordered. This is the final pipeline:

```
[{
$match: {
    "status": "delivered",
    "created_at": {
        $lte: ISODate("2021-12-31T01:11:11.000Z")
    },
    "created_at": {
        $gte: ISODate("2021-01-01T01:11:11.000Z")
    },
    "type": "delivery",
}
}, {
$project: {
    "customer_id": 1,
    "coverage_area_id": "$address.coverage_id",
}
}, {
$group: {
    "_id": {
        "customer_id": "$customer_id",
        "coverage": "$coverage_area_id"
    },
    "coverage_area_id": {
        $first: "$coverage_area_id"
    },
    "count": {
        $sum: 1
    },
}
}, {
$sort: {
    "_id.customer_id": 1,
    "count": -1
}
}, {
$group: {
    "_id": "$_id.customer_id",
    "items": {
        "$push": {
            "coverage_id": "$coverage_area_id",
            "occurs": "$count"
        }
    },
}
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort your query results in the descending order use:

```
$sort: {
"items.occurs": -1
}
```

See the docs [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)

Comment: I try this too and it doesn't work either, ¿Could it be something about how I am grouping the data that is affecting the ordering?